# Idris non-trivial type computation for tensor indexing

Tags: dependent-type, idris

I've been messing around with a simple tensor library, in which I have defined the following type.

```
data Tensor : Vect n Nat -> Type -> Type where
  Scalar : a -> Tensor [] a
  Dimension : Vect n (Tensor d a) -> Tensor (n :: d) a
```

The vector parameter of the type describes the tensor's "dimensions" or "shape". I am currently trying to define a function to safely index into a `Tensor`. I had planned to do this using `Fin`s but I ran into an issue. Because the `Tensor` is of unknown order, I could need any number of indices, each of which requiring a different upper bound. This means that a `Vect` of indices would be insufficient, because each index would have a different type. That drove me to look at using tuples (called "pairs" in Idris?) instead. I wrote the following function to compute the necessary type.

```
TensorIndex : Vect n Nat -> Type
TensorIndex []      = ()
TensorIndex (d::[]) = Fin d
TensorIndex (d::ds) = (Fin d, TensorIndex ds)
```

This function worked as I expected, calculating the appropriate index type from a dimension vector.

```
> TensorIndex [4,4,3] -- (Fin 4, Fin 4, Fin 3)
> TensorIndex [2] -- Fin 2
> TensorIndex [] -- ()
```

But when I tried to define the actual `index` function...

```
index : {d : Vect n Nat} -> TensorIndex d -> Tensor d a -> a
index () (Scalar x) = x
index (a,as) (Dimension xs) = index as $ index a xs
index a (Dimension xs) with (index a xs) | Tensor x = x
```

...Idris raised the following error on the second case (oddly enough it seemed perfectly okay with the first).

```
Type mismatch between
         (A, B) (Type of (a,as))
and
         TensorIndex (n :: d) (Expected type)
```

The error seems to imply that instead of treating `TensorIndex` as an extremely convoluted type synonym and evaluating it like I had hoped it would, it treated it as though it were defined with a `data` declaration; a "black-box type" so to speak. Where does Idris draw the line on this? Is there some way for me to rewrite `TensorIndex` so that it works the way I want it to? If not, can you think of any other way to write the `index` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your life becomes so much easier if you allow for a trailing `()` in your `TensorIndex`, since then you can just do

```
TensorIndex : Vect n Nat -> Type
TensorIndex []      = ()
TensorIndex (d::ds) = (Fin d, TensorIndex ds)

index : {ds : Vect n Nat} -> TensorIndex ds -> Tensor ds a -> a
index {ds = []} () (Scalar x) = x
index {ds = _ :: ds} (i, is) (Dimension xs) = index is (index i xs)
```

If you want to keep your definition of `TensorIndex`, you'll need to have separate cases for `ds = [_]` and `ds = _::_::_` to match the structure of `TensorIndex`:

```
TensorIndex : Vect n Nat -> Type
TensorIndex []      = ()
TensorIndex (d::[]) = Fin d
TensorIndex (d::ds) = (Fin d, TensorIndex ds)

index : {ds : Vect n Nat} -> TensorIndex ds -> Tensor ds a -> a
index {ds = []} () (Scalar x) = x
index {ds = _ :: []} i (Dimension xs) with (index i xs) | (Scalar x) = x
index {ds = _ :: _ :: _} (i, is) (Dimension xs) = index is (index i xs)
```

The reason this works and yours didn't is because here, each case of `index` corresponds exactly to one `TensorIndex` case, and so `TensorIndex ds` can be reduced.

Comment: @Kwarrtz: Answer updated to use your `TensorIndex` representation + an explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the update. So just to clarify, the part that I was missing was actually the implicit match on `ds`?

Comment: If you don't match on `ds`, you can still learn something about it by matching on `Scalar` vs `Dimension`. But just `Dimension` doesn't tell you if `TensorIndex ds` should be reduced per its second or its third case.

Answer (score 9):

Your definitions will be cleaner if you define `Tensor` by induction over the list of dimensions whilst the `Index` is defined as a datatype.

Indeed, at the moment you are forced to pattern-match on the implicit argument of type `Vect n Nat` to see what shape the index has. But if the index is defined directly as a piece of data, it then *constrains* the shape of the structure it indexes into and everything falls into place: the right piece of information arrives at the right time for the typechecker to be happy.

```
module Tensor

import Data.Fin
import Data.Vect

tensor : Vect n Nat -> Type -> Type
tensor []        a = a
tensor (m :: ms) a = Vect m (tensor ms a)

data Index : Vect n Nat -> Type where
  Here : Index []
  At   : Fin m -> Index ms -> Index (m :: ms)

index : Index ms -> tensor ms a -> a
index Here     a = a
index (At k i) v = index i $ index k v
```

Comment: Your suggestion is very helpful. I hadn't even considered this possibility, but it would simplify things considerably. I'm going to leave Cactus' answer as accepted because he answered first and answered my question more directly, but I appreciate the additional insight.

Comment: It's nice but it seems the absence of type constructor is then problematic to define functor interfaces for tensor, etc. ...