# Finding an implementation (of show) for an inductively defined type

Tags: polymorphism, typeclass, dependent-type, idris

The following snippet was from (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37461290/2129302):

```
tensor : Vect n Nat -> Type -> Type
tensor []        a = a
tensor (m :: ms) a = Vect m (tensor ms a)
```

I'd like to define the following:

```
mkStr : (Show a) => tensor shape a -> String
mkStr x = show x
```

But instead this gives the following error:

```
Can't find implementation for Show (tensor shape a)
```

However, on the REPL I can run "show [some tensor value...]". Why is this and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not showing `a`, you're showing `tensor shape a`. Thus, the following should work and you need to write type in the next way:

```
mkStr : (Show (tensor shape a)) => tensor shape a -> String
mkStr x = show x
```

Comment: Could you clarify why that is true? Surely if there's an implementation of `Show a`, so will `Show (tensor shape a)`. `Vect` itself provides `show`.

Comment: @RoastedYam `tensor` is a dependently typed function. Idris just doesn't try to guess whether it's enough to have `Show` constraint for type variable `a` or not for result of `tensor` function to satisfy `Show` constraint. Also because `shape` is type variable, not specific type. It's not `Vect`.