# Tensor definition with arbitrarily nested Vects

Tags: idris

I'm trying to create a `Tensor` type, but I'm having trouble working with the type signature for the constructor. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47492744/5986907) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37402279/5986907) question, they define a `Tensor` as a `Vect` of `Tensor`s, and in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47558158/5986907) question as a type alias for nested `Vect`s, but neither is right for my purposes. I need a `Tensor` to be atomic (it's not made of other `Tensor`s), and a distinct type (it doesn't inherit methods by virtue of being an alias).

I tried the following, which implicitly pulls out the shape and data type from an arbitrarily-nested `Vect` via `array_type`, and wraps it in a minimal `Tensor` type

```
import Data.Vect

total array_type: (shape: Vect r Nat) -> (dtype: Type) -> Type
array_type [] dtype = dtype
array_type (d :: ds) dtype = Vect d (array_type ds dtype)

data Tensor : (shape: Vect r Nat) -> (dtype: Type) -> Type where
  MkTensor : array_type shape dtype -> Tensor shape dtype
```

I've then defined various functions to check it's working at all (not included here). All this compiles fine, but when I try to define a function to multiply every element by two, I get in a real tangle. I've tried to first define it on a nested `Vect`:

```
times_two : Num dtype => array_type shape dtype -> array_type shape dtype
times_two (x :: xs) = (times_two x) :: (times_two xs)
times_two x = 2 * x
```

but I get

> When checking left hand side of times_two:
>   When checking an application of Main.times_two:
>           Can't disambiguate since no name has a suitable type:
>                   Prelude.List.::, Prelude.Stream.::, Data.Vect.::

Replacing `::` with `Data.Vect.::` didn't help. Is what I'm trying to do possible? and sensible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match on `array_type shape dtype` since it is not a data type. You need to figure out (i.e. match on) what the `shape` is before that type will simplify to a data type.

```
times_two {shape = []} x = 2 * x
times_two {shape = n :: ns} xs = map times_two xs
```

(In this case, the match on `xs` is inside `map`.)

Comment: ah, yes, and i'm glad the answer is a natural thing to do with tensors - gives me confidence my design isn't completely absurd

Comment: hmmm ... if I use `Tensor shape dtype` instead of `array_type shape dtype` and leave the RHS as holes, I get type mismatch between `Vect 0 Nat` and `Vect r Nat`. Will continue to dig

Comment: ah, simple, I just pull out the `array_type` from the `MkTensor` constructor and use what you've suggested as an inner function